# Python: upgrade numpy

Tags: python, numpy, debian

We have a problem, that we have installed numpy 1.6.2 on our python but we need 1.7.0
Is there a way we can upgrade this? We have try several ways but it still doesnt make sense.
We use Linux Debian with Python 2.7

Thanks

Comment: Looks more like a question for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Worked by installing manually package and then run easy_install :) thank you!